# Core Bluetooth - Advertising With Multiple Service Keys

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth

I've set up two applications on two separate devices.

The first acts as a Core Bluetooth Central Manager and scans for new devices:

```
- (id)init:(NSString *)channel {
    _channel = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:channel];
    return self;
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
    NSString *allKeys = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey];
    NSString *allOverflowKeys = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataOverflowServiceUUIDsKey];
}
```

The second acts as a Core Bluetooth Peripheral and broadcasts itself:

```
- (id)init:(NSString *)channel :(NSString *)username {
    _channel  = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:channel];
    _username = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:username];

    _advertisingData = @{CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:@[_username, _channel]};
    return self;
}

- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral{
    if(peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        [peripheralManager startAdvertising:_advertisingData];
        _isBroadcasting = YES;
    }
}
```

When I log the keys or overflow keys from the central manager, I always see exactly one UUID even though I've specified multiple for the peripheral. Why is that? I've attempted to grab the `firstObject` and `lastObject` as well, but it always results in returning the first UUID passed to `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` in the peripheral.

Comment: How are you calling `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`?  If you have known services why are you even examining the advertisement and overflow data?  Just specify those services to `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` and let Core Bluetooth do the work

Comment: `[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[_channel] options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)}];`

I'm examining the advertisement data because I'd like to detect the presence of a specific peripheral (an iOS device) while that device is an the background. The extra UUID acts as sort of a "username"

Comment: I think it would be faster and more reliable to just connect to the identified device and examine its characteristics and then disconnect if it isn't the device you are interested in. I suspect that you won't see the second service because you are scanning for the first - the second service may not be included in the advertisement of the first.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I've even tried to scan the services with an Android. The problem is not the scanning, it's the advertising that fails.

Comment: Same problem here. Tried to advertise two services, but only seeing one same uuid.